# What does the docker exec --privileged flag do?

Tags: docker, docker-exec

I've come across the `--privileged` flag for `docker exec`, but [the manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) does not provide much of an explanation:

> ```
> --privileged      Give extended privileges to the command
> ```

That's all. No more explanation or example.

Searching the web for more info, I only found descriptions of containers running in privileged mode, but it appears to me that this doesn't have to do anything with the privileged mode of `docker exec`. I assume that these privileges apply to the executed command, and I could image that it means that it is run under a privileged user (root). But then, I wonder what the difference would be compared to `docker exec -u 0`?

Comment: I'd guess it's the same as [`docker run --privileged`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities): a container is prohibited from doing many things, even as root, and the "privileged" option removes all of those controls.  I can't imagine a use case for needing this in a `docker exec` debugging shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default container runtimes go to great lengths to shield a container from the host system. Running in `--privileged` mode disables/bypasses most of these checks. This basically means that if you are root in a container you have the privileges of root on the host system. Is is only meant for special cases such as running Docker in Docker (for example in pipeline for sharing docker socket from the host) and should be avoided.