# gradle image failing with JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: docker, gradle, java-home

when I use  docker run -it  gradle:8.4.0-jdk17 /bin/bash
& gradle -v
it fails with 2 error

docker run -it  gradle:8.4.0-jdk17 /bin/bash
root@17a01c65ds84:/home/gradle# gradle -v
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/gradle': Operation not permitted

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /opt/java/openjdk

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Just an error message on its own usually isn't enough to diagnose an issue; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including the error in plain text and not an image?

Answer (score 0):

Running docker run with privileged command helped.

```
docker run --privileged=true
```

Comment: Running the container with `--privileged=true` is not secure. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75296684/916225